# How to change import functions source spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a script to automatically create a new sheet daily. So every day the sheet is created and moved to the second position(code 1). My problem is that I need to update the corresponding import formulas connected to different sheets. This is the import formula: =IMPORTRANGE("1X2wkyMOpafUbcV7BBW0ZyFYL0vSFyehqy0IEzEUa9Zg","Today!2:9") The sheet "Today" needs to switch to the day previous as an archive list.

**Code 1:**

```
function NewDay() {
  var numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab = -1
  var numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab = 60
  var rangeToClear = 'A3:M19'
 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   // get the spreadsheet object
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); // set the first sheet as active

  // Sets date for add tab & date for delete tab
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var today = new Date();
  var addWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() + (numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy");
  var deleteWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() - (numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy"); 
  
  // Adds tab
  ss.duplicateActiveSheet(); //Copies current sheet
  ss.renameActiveSheet(addWeek); //Renames sheet to date from above
  ss.moveActiveSheet(2); //Moves sheet to the first position  
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
function Example() {
  var numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab = -1
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();   // get the spreadsheet object
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[0]); // set the first sheet as active

  // Sets date for add tab & date for delete tab
  var MILLIS_PER_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var today = new Date();
  var addWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() + (numberOfDaysForwardForNextTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy");
  var deleteWeek = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(today.getTime() - (numberOfDaysBackwardForDeleteTab * MILLIS_PER_DAY)), "GMT+1", "MM-dd-yy"); 

  var newformula = ('importrange ')
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A6').activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(addWeek), true);
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1X2wkyMOpafUbcV7BBW0ZyFYL0vSFyehqy0IEzEUa9Zg","'addWeek'!2:9")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A18').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("157YxQP5waUniWPT8x-dbqzsqWP1-wlQWEpg9Z8See-c","'addWeek'!2:8")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A30').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1Y75DWBCSnLzFH-YWukTPROmUu7tCmNRG68Lx2rpwTls","'addWeek'!2:8")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A42').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1D8FA96acJbWmwVcN9lHE_pddtTdaCkCx3mXIdaN061k","'addWeek'!2:15")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A61').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1cHI1arXkCOICuLEWydN_UEnmDw2ilXfzkT_Hs7ugU4I","'addWeek'!2:8")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A73').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1vmTpOmnqGVY3zvD9ogzfDZKBHsx02MtJPbPHRU98paQ","'addWeek'!2:8")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('A74').activate();
}
```

Please Help Me, I'm so confused

Comment: This is not CSS related question. :D

Comment: Try it this way: `spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1X2wkyMOpafUbcV7BBW0ZyFYL0vSFyehqy0IEzEUa9Zg","' + addWeek + '!2:9")');
`

Comment: You might also have to escape the double quotes.  I'm not sure because I never use formulas.

Comment: What is the problem with the code? Are you getting any errors? Why is it not behaving in the way you want? What is the purpose of this line ` var newformula = ('importrange ')` ?

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### To concatenate strings you need the `+` operator

Instead of:

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1X2wkyMOpafUbcV7BBW0ZyFYL0vSFyehqy0IEzEUa9Zg","'addWeek'!2:9")');
```

You would need to do this:

```
spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("1X2wkyMOpafUbcV7BBW0ZyFYL0vSFyehqy0IEzEUa9Zg","' + addWeek + '!2:9")');
```